# Gunicorn workers throwing obscure error in log file

Tags: django, gunicorn

A virtual machine hosting my Django web application has recently been acting erratically (set up with gunicorn + nginx reverse proxy). Erratic being the server becomes unavailable for many minutes under high load (~85% CPU utilization). I looked into var/log/upstart/gunicorn.log, and I see the following at some parts of the log. Can anyone tell me what this is?

```
From cffi callback From cffi callback <function _osrandom_rand_bytes at 0x7fe2dd2b9b18>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/.allenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 66, in _osra$
<function _osrandom_rand_bytes at 0x7fe2dcc079b0>    @ffi_callback("int (*)(unsigned char *, int)",
  File "/home/myuser/.allenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 159, in handle_abort
:
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/myuser/.allenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 66, in _$
sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
    @ffi_callback("int (*)(unsigned char *, int)",
  File "/home/myuser/.allenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 159, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

I can't find much documentation about this error. Thanks in advance.

---

The contents of /etc/init/gunicorn.conf are:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid myuser
setgid www-data
chdir /home/myuser/projfolder/myproject/

exec /home/myuser/..allenvs/myenv/bin/gunicorn --chdir=/home/myuser/projfolder/ -w 17 --bind unix:/home/myuser/projfolder/myproject/myproject.sock -e ON_AZURE=1 -e HTTPS=on -e awsaccesskeyid=<some_id> -e awssecretkey=<some_key> myproject.wsgi:application
```

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880006/gunicorn-exits-because-https-request-from-django-fails-in-openssl